# sql server firewall

Tags: sql-server-2008

I look for installing an sql server express.
I check some post/tuto and saw that I need to enable tcp/ip, but did I need to do something with the firewall even if the database is only use on lan.

maybe it depend of my firewall.

Comment: This question is really hard to follow, so we have two choices: We can work on cleaning it up (at which point it sounds like it should goto [su]) or we can close it. Help us help you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, when you enabled TCP/IP did you make sure to restart SQL Server?
Did you run netstat -a from the command prompt to see what ports where listening?

You can force express to listen to a specific IP address by disabling dynamic ports in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx][1]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that ports 1433 and 1434 are not blocked, and you should be fine.